# List files with ls -1 containing specific string AND ignoring specific string

Tags: linux, ls

I have a script which is listing files to see if any exist. I have a selection of files, but some have a "(Demo)" suffix I want to ignore. I want to list all files that contain "I Need Help" but want to ignore the ones that contain the word "demo". Unfortunately this doesn't work;

```
ls -1 "I Need Help"* --ignore=*Demo* 2>/dev/null
```

Because a file named "I Need Help (Demo)" will still be listed.
I need to do it this way because sometimes "I Need Help" has extra words on the end (like "I Need Help Pretty Please", and THEN the "(Demo)" suffix. Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Extended globbing](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing)

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls "I Need Help"!(*Demo*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Options have to come before any filename arguments.

```
ls -1 --ignore="*Demo*" "I Need Help"*
```

However, this won't work because `--ignore` only filters out implied entries, not names that are explicitly listed as arguments. Implied entries occur when you list a directory and it expands that to all the files in the directory -- `--ignore` will filter names out of that list.

You can pipe the output to another command to filter out those rows:

```
ls -1 "I Need Help"* | grep -v Demo
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I unfortunately have the code `$fCheck = trim(shell_exec("ls -1 \"{$niceName} (Europe)\"* 2>/dev/null | grep -v 'YIKES!'"));` and have to exclude everything matching the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/lpiG4H/1 - is this possible?

Comment: @UnluckyForSome Can't you use `preg_match()` in PHP to exclude things that match the regexp?

Comment: I think so.. But how would I do this while still producing a similar row-seperated list? Sorry - i'm a complete newbie!

Comment: Use `explode()` to split `$fCheck` into an array of lines, use `array_filter()` to remove the lines that match the regexp, then use `implode()` to put it back into a string.

Comment: I also wonder why you're using `shell_exec()` instead of `glob()` to get a list of files that match a wildcard. The question was posed as a shell problem, but it seems like you really need to learn about built-in PHP capabilities.